# Check if Chronometer is running

Tags: android, chronometer

chronometer in android how to check whether chronometer is running or stop?
if start then i want to stop it and if not running then start chronometer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check this using boolean variable.when you start chronometer you set boolean variable true and when it stop you set boolean variable false.

```
boolean isChronometerRunning = false;
if (true)  // condition on which you check whether it's start or stop
{
    chronometer.start();
    isChronometerRunning  = true;
}
else
{
  chronometer.stop();
  isChronometerRunning  = false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can `extend` `Chronomter`, like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class MyChronometer extends Chronometer {

    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public MyChronometer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyChronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyChronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

}
```

And then just call `isRunning()`.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* strange that it doesn't expose that property. I don't really see an ideal way to check for it beyond keeping track on your own.

You could just take [the source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/Chronometer.java&q=android%20chronometer.java&type=cs) for that class, implement it in your project yourself, and add a method like this:

```
public boolean getStarted() {
    return mStarted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isChronometerRunning = false;

private Chronometer chronometer;

chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
chronometer.start();

isChronometerRunning = true;
```

Now whenever want to stop chronometer use the below code for checking chronometer is running or not.

```
    if (isChronometerRunning){
        chronometer_call.stop();
    }
```